# Create Jar Compatible With Java 7 With IntelliJ Using JDK8

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am using JDK8 on my normal desktop and I have a separate linux box that I am trying to run the Java program on.

The problem I'm running into is that the linux box is running jdk7, so the computer has JRE7 basically that it is running off of. My question is, is it possible to create a jar file in JDK8 that will be compatible with java 7?

I'm using IntelliJ to compile. I tried to compile in 1.7, but it gave an error when I did end up trying to do it. I compile it here:

[image]

In 1.8 it works fine to compile, but when I try to compile in 1.7 it doesn't work.

I know the short answer is to update the linux to JRE 8. But I am curious, is there a way to make it backwards compatible? Or is the other answer to simply install JDK7 on the desktop in order for it to run on the linux box using JRE7?

Comment: So, you're using Java 8 functionality?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils  think what they're saying is that even though they're not using JDK 8 functionality but still compiling using JDK 8, will it be backwards compatible with JRE 7 because they're not using JDK 8 functionality. To which the answer is no (see my answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java programs built with JDK 8 will only run on machines running JRE 8 (or higher).

I found this when trying to compile classes on my local Linux machine (using JDK 8) and deploying to a remote server running JRE 7. The classes just wouldn't work (like you're finding).

If you want to use JRE 8 on linux, I recommend using the `oracle-java8-installer` package from `webupd8team`. Installation instructions found [here (assuming Debian based distro)](http://tecadmin.net/install-oracle-java-8-jdk-8-ubuntu-via-ppa/).

If you want to compile to JDK 7, it's not good enough to only have JDK 8  installed and pick to compile 1.7. You need JDK 7 installed to and restage your project to use JDK 7.

---

The thing you have to remember is that the difference between JRE/JDK versions is **not just** the extra features developers can use (e.g Lambda functions) but it's also that the JRE itself is improved (efficiency, garbage collection, etc.).
As a extreme example: If you wrote code that only used JDK 1 features but compiled it using JDK 8, it wouldn't run on a machine running JRE 1 because the Java classes had been compiled with JRE 8 in mind.

Do note though, that if you're Java Code uses only features from JDK 7 or 6 etc., you might think it good practice to compile using the minimum JDK required to allow for compatibility with more machines. Well...you'd have that compatibility but at a cost of using inefficient, out of date, possibly vulnerable compiled classes (At little extreme, but you get my point).

Comment: Despite this, if they aren't using J8 features *and* they have 7 installed then they can indeed switch to compile it under 7.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using any [new Java 8 features](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8-whats-new-2157071.html)? Because if you are, this means you cannot build the project against the JRE7.

If you are not using any Java 8 features, you can build to Java 7 most easily by downloading the JDK7 and switching the project to use that instead of the JDK8.

Answer (score 0):

You should also set project language level to 1.7 (and module language level(s) as well, if they're different). It's done in Project Structure settings dialog. After that the project should compile.

Note that you shouldn't use any of the APIs that appeared in 1.8, but such usages will most likely be highlighted in the editor.